# How to get facebook page id from facebook page name

Tags: javascript, php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'd like to know how to get fb page id from fb page name.

As you can see [here](https://my.impress.ly/intro) it shows number of likes from facebook page name.

How can I do this?
Any help would be appreciate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It´s a simple API call:

```
/page-name?fields=id,name,fan_count
```

You will get the ID, the name of the Page and the likes. For example: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=bladauhu%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname%2Cfan_count&version=v2.8

Result:

```
{
  "id": "186482018683",
  "name": "SV Blada UHU",
  "fan_count": 218
}
```

You can also use the Search API if you want to search for a Page by its full name: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#search

For example: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=search%3Ftype%3Dpage%26q%3DBottom%20of%20the%20Hill&version=v2.8

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I think you misunderstood. Have you looked link I attached?

Comment: your question is "How to get facebook page id from facebook page name", that´s exactly what i answered. if you want to get the likes too, just add the correct field. i added it to my answer.

Comment: i will also add some information about the search api in my answer

Comment: That api is getting name from page id. I want to get page id from page name.

Comment: that is exactly what my answer is about ;)

Comment: what would you enter as page name? can i get an example? maybe i can make it more clear for you then.

Comment: As you can see on impress.ly you could input "Bottom of the Hill", or "Matrix Fillmore"

Comment: that is why i added the search api to my answer, check out the link

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125098/discussion-between-guru-and-luschn).

Comment: i have added an example for the search api

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing, and using that example URL I just get an empty 'data' output.  I've got a user access token (with no permissions needed I think) and have tried both `search?type=page&q=Bottom of the Hill` and `search?q=107&type=page&fields=id,name,location` structures, any suggestions much appreciated

Comment: you are doing a search, that´s a completely different thing. i am not sure if searching for pages is still available, check out the changelog. as lot has changed recently.

Comment: ```
(#10) Object does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permission or reviewable feature, or does not support this operation. This endpoint requires the 'pages_read_engagement' permission or the 'Page Public Content Access' feature or the 'Page Public Metadata Access' feature.
```

I got this error, did I something wrong ?

Comment: the answer is quite old, nowadays you need to apply for page public content access, for example. it is a bit more complicated now afaik, i am afraid :)